# Statically link Qt application with QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to statically link a Qt application which uses the QML module. Previously when it did not include QML I was able to build and link it statially.

In the compile output I get the following message:

```
'C:\Qt\5.4\qtbase\bin\qmlimportscanner.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The `qmlimportscanner.exe` is indeed missing from my installation. After some research the only place I have found this file is the [qt5-declarative-tools](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Fqt5-declarative-tools%2Fqt5-declarative-tools-5.4.1-1&grep=as) Cygwin package.

In the maintenence tool I was not able to identify any package that I would suspect to contain this tool. How do I get the `qmlimportscanner.exe`?

I am running Windows 8.1 and Qt 5.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the declarative module of Qt was not build. I have built a static version of Qt a few month ago, and I do not remember taking out the declarative module explicitly. Maybe I did, or maybe it is indeed not built by default. Anyway this modul can be buil by itself using nmake (or jom):

```
nmake module-qtdeclarative
```

Comment: This worked for me as well on Windows 7 using Qt 5.6 and MSVC13.  I also only noticed the problem of the missing `qmlimportscanner.exe` after doing `nmake clean` followed by `qmake -r QT_BUILD_PARTS="lib tools"`.  Possibly one of those steps deleted `qmlimportscanner`.